# Glassmapper Error after upgrade to Sitecore 8.2

Tags: glass-mapper, upgrade

I upgraded my dev instance from Sitecore 8.1 Update 2, to Sitecore 8.2.

It indicated that my upgrade was successful.   But now I get this error message when I try to access my site or after login to the admin:

> Attempt by method 'Glass.Mapper.Sc.Utilities.get_IsPageEditor()' to
>   access method 'Sitecore.Context+PageMode.get_IsPageEditor()' failed.

Looking in the bin folder it appears that the site currently has the DLLs for:

- Glass.Mapper: 4.2.3.190
- Glass.Mapper.Sc: 4.2.3.190
- Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc: 4.2.3.190
- Glass.Mapper.Sc.CastleWindsor.dll:
  3.5.3.0

Are these correct?  :-(

Comment: Well `Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsPageEditor` was deprecated, in favor of `Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditor`. Without having looked too deeply, I would check if there is a later version of Glass.Mapper to upgrade to and/or if there is a `Glass.Mapper.Sc.Utilities.IsExperienceEditor` method or a method that calls the non-deprecated method

Comment: I did a global search and don't see any references to IsPageEditor in my code.   It seems to be failing on this line: @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("header_content")

Comment: @CoreySmith same error, but does not -appear- to be the same cause.  I don't have a separate NuGet package installed for MVC as indicated as the cause for the issue for that error.